# Regarding include js or cs file in view ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

1) the below code i could write in my view to download any js or cs file at client side

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/myScriptFile.js"></script>

OR

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/myScriptFile.js")

OR

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/myScriptFile.js")"></script>
```

then why we need to write my js code inside script section like below one?

```
@section Scripts{
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        $("#submit1").click(function () {
            alert("button");
        });

     });
  </script>

}
```

2) what is the difference between the below two way to include js/css file in view ?

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/myScriptFile.js")
OR
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/myScriptFile.js")"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each approach will get you the same end result.  In my experience, I find the  approach to be more flexible and scalable as far as code maintenance goes.  I'm not a fan of rendering HTML code through helpers for this reason.  I hope this helps.